# animation for the round circle progress bar on load

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

can any one please help me how to start animating the round progress bar border after loading the page , i need animation to all the percentages ...please suggest me any help ...thanks a lot if any help me regarding the issue .

please give one reference how to do for this example to start the animation while loading

i need animation to similar to this [click here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/nrDmZ)

```css
.progress-circle {
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: 20px;
   position: relative; /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
   padding: 0;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   background-color: #F2E9E1; 
   border-radius: 50%;
   line-height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:after{
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.35em;
    left: 0.35em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 4.3em;
    height: 4.3em;
    background-color: white;
    content: " ";
}
/* Text inside the control */
.progress-circle span {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: #53777A;
    z-index: 2;
}
.left-half-clipper { 
   /* a round circle */
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   position: absolute; /* needed for clipping */
   clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em); /* clips the whole left half*/ 
}
/* when p>50, don't clip left half*/
.progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
   clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
}
.value-bar {
   /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
   then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
   to escape the outer clipping path.*/ 
   position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
   clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 0.45em solid #53777A; /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
   /*background-color: #4D642D;*/ /* for debug */
   box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
/* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */
.progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
   /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
   position: absolute; /*needed for clipping*/
   clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
   background-color: #53777A;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 5em;
   height: 5em;
}
.progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar{ display: none; }


/* Progress bar rotation position */
.progress-circle.p0 .value-bar { display: none; }
.progress-circle.p1 .value-bar { transform: rotate(4deg); }
.progress-circle.p2 .value-bar { transform: rotate(7deg); }
.progress-circle.p3 .value-bar { transform: rotate(11deg); }
.progress-circle.p4 .value-bar { transform: rotate(14deg); }
.progress-circle.p5 .value-bar { transform: rotate(18deg); }
.progress-circle.p6 .value-bar { transform: rotate(22deg); }
.progress-circle.p7 .value-bar { transform: rotate(25deg); }
.progress-circle.p8 .value-bar { transform: rotate(29deg); }
.progress-circle.p9 .value-bar { transform: rotate(32deg); }
.progress-circle.p10 .value-bar { transform: rotate(36deg); }
.progress-circle.p11 .value-bar { transform: rotate(40deg); }
.progress-circle.p12 .value-bar { transform: rotate(43deg); }
.progress-circle.p13 .value-bar { transform: rotate(47deg); }
.progress-circle.p14 .value-bar { transform: rotate(50deg); }
.progress-circle.p15 .value-bar { transform: rotate(54deg); }
.progress-circle.p16 .value-bar { transform: rotate(58deg); }
.progress-circle.p17 .value-bar { transform: rotate(61deg); }
.progress-circle.p18 .value-bar { transform: rotate(65deg); }
.progress-circle.p19 .value-bar { transform: rotate(68deg); }
.progress-circle.p20 .value-bar { transform: rotate(72deg); }
.progress-circle.p21 .value-bar { transform: rotate(76deg); }
.progress-circle.p22 .value-bar { transform: rotate(79deg); }
.progress-circle.p23 .value-bar { transform: rotate(83deg); }
.progress-circle.p24 .value-bar { transform: rotate(86deg); }
.progress-circle.p25 .value-bar { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.progress-circle.p26 .value-bar { transform: rotate(94deg); }
.progress-circle.p27 .value-bar { transform: rotate(97deg); }
.progress-circle.p28 .value-bar { transform: rotate(101deg); }
.progress-circle.p29 .value-bar { transform: rotate(104deg); }
.progress-circle.p30 .value-bar { transform: rotate(108deg); }
.progress-circle.p31 .value-bar { transform: rotate(112deg); }
.progress-circle.p32 .value-bar { transform: rotate(115deg); }
.progress-circle.p33 .value-bar { transform: rotate(119deg); }
.progress-circle.p34 .value-bar { transform: rotate(122deg); }
.progress-circle.p35 .value-bar { transform: rotate(126deg); }
.progress-circle.p36 .value-bar { transform: rotate(130deg); }
.progress-circle.p37 .value-bar { transform: rotate(133deg); }
.progress-circle.p38 .value-bar { transform: rotate(137deg); }
.progress-circle.p39 .value-bar { transform: rotate(140deg); }
.progress-circle.p40 .value-bar { transform: rotate(144deg); }
.progress-circle.p41 .value-bar { transform: rotate(148deg); }
.progress-circle.p42 .value-bar { transform: rotate(151deg); }
.progress-circle.p43 .value-bar { transform: rotate(155deg); }
.progress-circle.p44 .value-bar { transform: rotate(158deg); }
.progress-circle.p45 .value-bar { transform: rotate(162deg); }
.progress-circle.p46 .value-bar { transform: rotate(166deg); }
.progress-circle.p47 .value-bar { transform: rotate(169deg); }
.progress-circle.p48 .value-bar { transform: rotate(173deg); }
.progress-circle.p49 .value-bar { transform: rotate(176deg); }
.progress-circle.p50 .value-bar { transform: rotate(180deg); }
.progress-circle.p51 .value-bar { transform: rotate(184deg); }
.progress-circle.p52 .value-bar { transform: rotate(187deg); }
.progress-circle.p53 .value-bar { transform: rotate(191deg); }
.progress-circle.p54 .value-bar { transform: rotate(194deg); }
.progress-circle.p55 .value-bar { transform: rotate(198deg); }
.progress-circle.p56 .value-bar { transform: rotate(202deg); }
.progress-circle.p57 .value-bar { transform: rotate(205deg); }
.progress-circle.p58 .value-bar { transform: rotate(209deg); }
.progress-circle.p59 .value-bar { transform: rotate(212deg); }
.progress-circle.p60 .value-bar { transform: rotate(216deg); }
.progress-circle.p61 .value-bar { transform: rotate(220deg); }
.progress-circle.p62 .value-bar { transform: rotate(223deg); }
.progress-circle.p63 .value-bar { transform: rotate(227deg); }
.progress-circle.p64 .value-bar { transform: rotate(230deg); }
.progress-circle.p65 .value-bar { transform: rotate(234deg); }
.progress-circle.p66 .value-bar { transform: rotate(238deg); }
.progress-circle.p67 .value-bar { transform: rotate(241deg); }
.progress-circle.p68 .value-bar { transform: rotate(245deg); }
.progress-circle.p69 .value-bar { transform: rotate(248deg); }
.progress-circle.p70 .value-bar { transform: rotate(252deg); }
.progress-circle.p71 .value-bar { transform: rotate(256deg); }
.progress-circle.p72 .value-bar { transform: rotate(259deg); }
.progress-circle.p73 .value-bar { transform: rotate(263deg); }
.progress-circle.p74 .value-bar { transform: rotate(266deg); }
.progress-circle.p75 .value-bar { transform: rotate(270deg); }
.progress-circle.p76 .value-bar { transform: rotate(274deg); }
.progress-circle.p77 .value-bar { transform: rotate(277deg); }
.progress-circle.p78 .value-bar { transform: rotate(281deg); }
.progress-circle.p79 .value-bar { transform: rotate(284deg); }
.progress-circle.p80 .value-bar { transform: rotate(288deg); }
.progress-circle.p81 .value-bar { transform: rotate(292deg); }
.progress-circle.p82 .value-bar { transform: rotate(295deg); }
.progress-circle.p83 .value-bar { transform: rotate(299deg); }
.progress-circle.p84 .value-bar { transform: rotate(302deg); }
.progress-circle.p85 .value-bar { transform: rotate(306deg); }
.progress-circle.p86 .value-bar { transform: rotate(310deg); }
.progress-circle.p87 .value-bar { transform: rotate(313deg); }
.progress-circle.p88 .value-bar { transform: rotate(317deg); }
.progress-circle.p89 .value-bar { transform: rotate(320deg); }
.progress-circle.p90 .value-bar { transform: rotate(324deg); }
.progress-circle.p91 .value-bar { transform: rotate(328deg); }
.progress-circle.p92 .value-bar { transform: rotate(331deg); }
.progress-circle.p93 .value-bar { transform: rotate(335deg); }
.progress-circle.p94 .value-bar { transform: rotate(338deg); }
.progress-circle.p95 .value-bar { transform: rotate(342deg); }
.progress-circle.p96 .value-bar { transform: rotate(346deg); }
.progress-circle.p97 .value-bar { transform: rotate(349deg); }
.progress-circle.p98 .value-bar { transform: rotate(353deg); }
.progress-circle.p99 .value-bar { transform: rotate(356deg); }
.progress-circle.p100 .value-bar { transform: rotate(360deg); }
.progres-circle{
    animation: loading-2 1.5s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
@keyframes loading-1{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-2{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
        transform: rotate(144deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-3{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-4{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
        transform: rotate(36deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loading-5{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
        transform: rotate(126deg);
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px){
    .progress-circle{ margin-bottom: 20px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-circle p10">
   <span>10%</span>
   <div class="left-half-clipper">
      <div class="first50-bar"></div>
      <div class="value-bar"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle p33">
   <span>33%</span>
   <div class="left-half-clipper">
      <div class="first50-bar"></div>
      <div class="value-bar"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p66">
   <span>66%</span>
   <div class="left-half-clipper">
      <div class="first50-bar"></div>
      <div class="value-bar"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p77">
   <span>77%</span>
   <div class="left-half-clipper">
      <div class="first50-bar"></div>
      <div class="value-bar"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p99">
   <span>99%</span>
   <div class="left-half-clipper">
      <div class="first50-bar"></div>
      <div class="value-bar"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p100">
   <span>100%</span>
   <div class="left-half-clipper">
      <div class="first50-bar"></div>
      <div class="value-bar"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you do it as the example you provided?

Answer (score 1):

So if you hide the black percentage circle, you will see they have used CSS to create two half-circles with borders, and they are rotating them based on the percentage value:

[image]

Here is their code for the half circle border:

```
.progress-bar {
    animation: loading-2 1.5s linear forwards 1.8s;
    border-color: #049dff;
    border-top-right-radius: 80px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
    border-left: 0;
    transform-origin: center left;
}
```

Notice that they've used `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to make sure the animation remains where it ends.